# ld-linux --verify exit codes

Tags: linux

Checking the source from /usr/bin/ldd, I see that it uses ld-linux to find the dependencies of an executable, although it first calls ld-linux with the --verify argument. Then the script acts differently according to the exit code of the ld-linux --verify call.

The man page for ld-linux does not provide any info on exit codes, and a Google search turns nothing of value. Is there some documentation anywhere (other than by looking at ld-linux's source code) that provides a list of exit codes for ld-linux --verfify and their respective meanings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find any documentation, but...

```
  if (__builtin_expect (mode, normal) == verify)
    {
      /* We were called just to verify that this is a dynamic
         executable using us as the program interpreter.  Exit with an
         error if we were not able to load the binary or no interpreter
         is specified (i.e., this is no dynamically linked binary.  */
      if (main_map->l_ld == NULL)
        _exit (1);

      /* We allow here some platform specific code.  */
#ifdef DISTINGUISH_LIB_VERSIONS
      DISTINGUISH_LIB_VERSIONS;
#endif
      _exit (has_interp ? 0 : 2);
    }
```

So...

- 0 means success, i.e. "program  is  dynamically  linked  and  this 
  dynamic linker can handle it"
- 1 means ld-linux was "not able to load the binary" (I got
  this when I ran ld-linux with non-existent, non-binary or static binary file)
- 2 means "no interpreter is specified". More specifically, there is no element with p_type equal PT_INTERP in program header table (I get this when I run ld-linux with shared library)

There are no other codes.

Answer (score 1):

I did some experiments and exit status is zero on success and 1 on failure.  This includes grotesque abuse such as asking it to verify a shell script.

You'd be safe assuming zero on success, nonzero on failure, and no other information.

Comment: That's not the case unfortunately. Zero is indeed "success", but there are a plethora of nonzero values, with plenty of meaning for each. e.g., ldd acts one way if the return value is either 0 or 2, and another way if the return value is 5. However, I have no idea what 2 means (5 means "invoked with __libc_enable_secure according to some comment in the script). So I can only suppose 2 means something, and there is a 3 and a 4 (at least).

Comment: @Fred: Bletch.  You haven't told us why you need to know, but the only advice I have left for you is from a long time ago and far, far away: use the source, Luke!